# gcc: fatal error: no input files

Tags: 14.04, c++, monodevelop

I just installed Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) for the first time and I went straight to programming. I installed MonoDevelop and tried to create my first C++ program on Ubuntu.

However, when I tried to build the program I got the following error:

```
Building Solution: Lab (Debug)

Building: Lab (Debug)
Performing main compilation...

Precompiling headers

Compiling source to object files

Generating binary "Lab" from object files
gcc -o "/home/vincent/Desktop/Programming/C++/Lab/Lab/bin/Debug/Lab"   
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

**C++ main.cpp file from the Lab solution**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "123" << endl;
    getchar();  

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate stackexchange for this.
In advance, thanks.

Comment: The error means that there was no file name passed into gcc. `gcc -o "/home/vincent/Desktop/Programming/C++/Lab/Lab/bin/Debug/Lab"` specified the output file; it doesn't specify what file to read in and compile.

Comment: I'm on MonoDevelop, maybe there's a way to specify it? I think I'm on the wrong stackexchange though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the monodevelop interface, but you probably need to find out how to *add* the main.cpp file to your project

Comment: remove stdio.h file and try :)

Comment: Removed stdio.h. Still not working. :/